# How to make ajax call and show error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Two of the action of My registration controller is new and create.

```
  def new
    @regist = Regist.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @regist }
    end
  end

  def create
    @regist = Regist.new(regist_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @regist.save
        format.html { redirect_to @regist, notice: 'Regist was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @regist, status: :created, location: @regist }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @regist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And the new form contain following code.

```
<%= form_for(@regist) do |f| %>
  <% if @regist.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@regist.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this regist from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @regist.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_select :student_id, Student.all, :id, :name %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_select :semester_id, Semester.all, :id, :name %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="field">

    <% for subject in Subject.find(:all) %>
        <%= check_box_tag "regist[subject_ids][]", subject.id %>
        <%= subject.name %><br>
    <% end %>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :date_of_birth %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :date_of_birth %>
    </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now, when someone click on submit button I want to make ajax call using remote true if there are validation errors and show the errors without reloading the page. And if there are no validation errors I want the user to be redirected to show page. How can I do this?

Comment: in the else part of your create add format.js, and create a file create.js.erb in your view, in this file render a partial that contains your above form with errors and replaced the old form using javascript/jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should add a **remote: true** to your existing form to allow remote action.
TODO this just add on the first line of your form the remote: true,

```
<%= form_for(@regist, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

the rest leave it as it is. Then you need to make your **controller** to respond to remote calls, therefore you need to alter the responds_to block of create action:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @regist.save
    format.html { redirect_to @regist, notice: 'Regist was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @regist, status: :created, location: @regist }
    format.js   { render js: "window.location.href='"+regists_path+"'"}
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @regist.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.js
  end
end
```

The last step you have to do is to add a file to your app/views/regists/ directory
where you should add a **create.js.erb** file:

```
<% if @regist.errors.any? %>
  $('#new_regist').effect('highlight', { color: '#FF0000'}, 1000); // for highlighting
  // or add here whatever jquery response you want to have to your views.
<% end %>
```

You will get your validation errors displayed like before above the form.
You have to add the redirect to your controller to the desirable action of your choice. I have added for you a **window.location.href** as a response to the **regists_path**.